# Python struct.pack little endian = big endian

Tags: python, struct, endianness

I am trying to ensure that some data I have is encoded as big endian binary. I am using the struct module to do this. However, the result I get for converting both to big or little endian is identical. Why?

```
import sys
import json
import struct

data = {
    "val1": 20,
    "val2": 24
}

b = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf-8")

little = struct.pack(f"<{len(b)}s", b)
big = struct.pack(f">{len(b)}s", b)

print(f"System byteorder: {sys.byteorder}")
print(f"data:\t{b}")
print(f"little:\t{little}")
print(f"big:\t{big}")
print((big == little) and (little == b))



val = 25
b = bytes([val])

big = struct.pack(">H", val)
little = struct.pack("<H", val)

print()
print()
print(f"data:\t{b}")
print(f"little:\t{little}")
print(f"big:\t{big}")
print((big == little) and (little == b))
```

Gives the following result

```
System byteorder: little
data:   b'{"val1": 20, "val2": 24}'
little: b'{"val1": 20, "val2": 24}'
big:    b'{"val1": 20, "val2": 24}'
True


data:   b'\x19'
little: b'\x19\x00'
big:    b'\x00\x19'
False
```

Comment: Bytestrings don't have endianness.

Comment: Strings (of bytes) are byte-oriented, they don't have endianness. As you see with the `H` code, the endianness is taken into account for things that are individually larger than bytes.

Comment: Thanks ShadowRanger, you've cleared my confusion. My misconception was that I didn't understand each element of the string of bytes was considered individually. Since each character individually is just one byte, it makes sense to me now that there's no need to define the order. I was previously considering the byte string as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the format specifier "s" for `char[]`, which is just a string of octets. A string of char/octet doesn't have an endianness. When you use "H", `unsigned short` you see big/little are oppositely ordered.